# All Corona SDK projects are offcenter in some way on the stage, even from example code

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I think the title says it all but I will elaborate.

I am beginning to learn the Corona SDK, and am on a Windows computer using the latest Corona nightly. My IDE is LUA Glider.

Every time I compile example code, it always displays in a funky way on the stage. It is never centered correctly.

I always need to find a way to insert something like :

```
_X = display.contentWidth / 2
_Y = display.contentHeight / 2
```

And then manually set the instances to those variables in order for backgrounds and widgets to display properly.

I've purchased a couple of books, and both of them give example code that simply does not center properly. I also took code directly from coronalabs.com, which also displays poorly. An example follows.

(As I said, it is directly copied from http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newTableView.html but displays poorly for me.)

Could someone please tell me if I am losing my mind or if something I am doing is a bit sloppy?

For example :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCoMU.jpg

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

-- The "onRowRender" function may go here (see example under "Inserting Rows", above)

-- Create the widget
local tableView = widget.newTableView
{
    left = 200,
    top = 200,
    height = 330,
    width = 300,
    onRowRender = onRowRender,
    onRowTouch = onRowTouch,
    listener = scrollListener
}

-- Insert 40 rows
for i = 1, 40 do
    -- Insert a row into the tableView
    tableView:insertRow{}
end
```

Comment: I guess i've already seen such a problem couple of questions ago. Sadly, can't find it. The problem was wit Corona API changes and reference point being not the top left corner anymore.

Comment: Is there any sort of solution to this that you know of to change the reference point back for my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Corona SDK builds 1260 and earlier, things that let you set an X, Y when you create the object like:

```
local myRect = display.newRect( 100, 100, 200, 200)
```

This would create a 200x200 square that had it's top, left corner at 100, 100.  But somethings that X, Y was the center.  With the Graphics 2.0 engine (build #'s starting with 2000 -- not counting the 2013 at the beginning, all of that changed.  Those X, Y's are now always the center point of the object.  The same rectangle will now be centered at 100, 100 and have its top left at 0, 0.

Without knowing the specific build number it will be hard to know what is going on.  Now with widget code, you are telling it to draw the top, left corner at 200, 200 and that appears to be what it's doing.  If you want that tableView to start at the top left corner, set those values to 0, 0

Comment: Done. Sorry, fairly new to this system.